# getting dex error on implementing OneSignal

Tags: android

in android after read documentation of `OneSignal` and implementing that on `Gradle` i get this error:

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
>
> > java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge
> >     dex

my `Gradle` in app folder:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin' version '0.7.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.onesignal.androidsdk.onesignal-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ir.kiyanis.application"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    packagingOptions {
        ...
    }

    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id: "MY KEY IS HERE",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "REMOTE"]
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    maven { url "https://clojars.org/repo/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    ...
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:+'
    ...
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.5, 3.99.99]'
}
```

i set this implementation by `OneSignal` documentation, how can i resolve this problem?

my `Application` class:

```
public class Application extends MultiDexApplication {
    ...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        OneSignal.startInit(this)
                .inFocusDisplaying(OneSignal.OSInFocusDisplayOption.Notification)
                .unsubscribeWhenNotificationsAreDisabled(true)
                .init();
}
```

and then my manifest is:

```
<application
        android:name=".Application"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
dexOptions {
    jumboMode true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"

}
```